# Oracle Performance: Partition Split vs Insert Append

Tags: oracle, bulkinsert, database-partitioning

I am currently refactoring a data loading process in Oracle 12c and am exploring partitioning as a solution. My data is categorised by date and I have ~500k records per date which seems to fit the "minimum optimal" for partitioning, or so I am told. The original plan was to use a staging table to load the data, then add a dummy partition to the main table and perform a partition exchange. However, my data load contains data from several days rather than from one day. Preliminary research suggests there are two methods to solve this problem:

**Option 1: Perform the partition exchange, then split the large partition in a loop**

```
ALTER TABLE MAIN_TABLE ADD PARTITION DUMMY_PARTITION VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-1-9999', 'DD-MM-YYYY'));

ALTER TABLE MAIN_TABLE
EXCHANGE PARTITION DUMMY_PARTITION
WITH TABLE STAGING_TABLE
WITHOUT VALIDATION UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES;

BEGIN
   FOR row IN (select distinct to_char(DATE_FIELD+1, 'YYYYMMDD') DATE_FIELD from PARTITIONED_TABLE order by DATE_FIELD)
   LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE MAIN_TABLE SPLIT PARTITION DUMMY_PARTITION AT (TO_DATE('''||row.DATE_FIELD||''', ''YYYYMMDD'')) INTO (PARTITION p'||row.DATE_FIELD||', PARTITION DUMMY_PARTITION) UPDATE GLOBAL INDEXES';
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**Option 2: Perform an insert append**

```
INSERT /*+ append */ INTO MAIN_TABLE SELECT * FROM STAGING_TABLE;
```

Somehow, it seems like splitting the partition is a slower process than doing the insert. Is this expected behaviour or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you need to use a staging table? Can you not insert directly into the main partitioned table?

Answer (score 0):

There is a fast split optimization, depending on the circumstances. However from your description, I would simply do the INSERT /+* APPEND */
You may want to employ some parallelism too, if you have the resources and you are looking to speed up the inserts.